# why the if else statement does not run the else statement?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a problem with my `if` and `else` statement in PHP where it never runs the `else` statement.

The input form is in HTML:

```html
   <input type="radio" name="marital_stat" id="single" value="single" />Single
   <input type="radio" name="marital_stat" id="married" value="married" />Married

   <input name="age" type="text" size="5" maxlength="3" placeholder="30" required/>

   <input name="work" type="radio" id="employee" value="employee" />Employee
   <input name="work" type="radio" id="own" value="own" />
    Own Business 
   <input name="work" type="radio" id="jobless" value="jobless" />Jobless

   <input name="place" type="radio" id="urban" value="urban" />Urban
   <input name="place" type="radio" id="rural" value="rural" />Rural</td>
```

Here is the PHP Code:

```php
if ($marital_stat == 'married')
{
    if ($age >= 18 || $age < 59)
    { 
        if ($work == 'jobless')
        { 
            if ($place == 'rural') { $loan_credibility == 5; }
        }
    }
}
else if ($marital_stat == 'single')
{ 
    if ($age >= 18 || $age < 59)
    {
        if ($work == 'employee')
        { 
            if ($place == 'rural') { $loan_credibility == 1; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a condition that will display some output:

```php
$A = 'positive';
$B = 'negative';

if ($loan_credibility == 5 ){
    echo $B ;}
else{
    echo $A;
}
```

Comment: what's the input to the if? forst guess the $marital_stat is neither married nor single - also, it would help to know which language is this.

Comment: Please provide a complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: hi @LorenzoBoccaccia, i've added some input code for the if and the language for if else is in php language.

Comment: @Farahin Samsudin: have you updated `$loan_credibility == 1;` and `$loan_credibility == 5` to use a single equal sign, not double?  If so, the please update your example code  ...@Mohamed Belal pointed this out in his answer.  So two problems to sum this up 1) incorrect `if-else if-else` and incorrect `=` vs `==`

Comment: @Farahin Samsudin see my updated answer with combined fixes - thanks.

Comment: Have you verified that `$marital_stat`, `$age`, `$work`, and `$place` contain the values you're expecting? Maybe you should share the code that sets those variables.

Comment: Are you sure each of your variables have values such that the evaluations be be true?  Otherwise... `The elseif statement is only executed if the preceding if expression and any preceding elseif expressions evaluated to FALSE, and the current elseif expression evaluated to TRUE.` (from http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php) - meaning if `$marital_stat` != 'married' *and* `$age`, `$work` and `$place` don't evaluate then you won't get what you're expecting

Comment: Can `$marital_stat` have a value other than `married` or `single`?

Comment: I hope this isn't a production code and you are giving (or not) loans on that algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

As I see you make `$loan_credibility == 5;` or `1`; the `==` only used in equality statement it checks the two sides if they equal and you have to use `=` to set value, not `==` so it will be `$loan_credibility = 5;` or `1`;

Comment: Please don't forget to mark best answer as correct for this question

Comment: i've tried as you suggested, it changed the result. but when i'm trying click the input for the positive result, it keep display the negative result.

Comment: Are you sure that the condition which in if statement are being made with correct values to produce $loan_credibility ?

Comment: i'm pretty sure. basically, it depends on job and place. if employee + urban the result will be negative. and if jobless + rural/ urban will be also negative. but if employee + rural, it should display positive. so, i've put the value 5 to return the negative statement and 1 for positive statement

Answer (score 0):

You have no `else` clause (which logically is necessary when using `else if`)...

```
if (condition) {
    code to be executed if condition is true;
} elseif (condition) {
    code to be executed if condition is true;
} else {
    code to be executed if condition is false;
}
```

Do any of the following (#1 or #2 make the most sense)...

1. Make your `else if` into a separate `if` block
2. Change `else if` to `else`
3. Or add an `else` clause

Also, as @Mohamed Belal pointed out, when setting variables use `=` not `==`.

So two things to fix your problem: 1) `if-else if-else` logic and 2) `=` vs `==`...

```
if ($marital_stat == 'married')
{
    if ($age >= 18 || $age < 59)
    { 
        if ($work == 'jobless')
        { 
            if ($place == 'rural') { $loan_credibility = 5; }
        }
    }
}

if ($marital_stat == 'single')
{ 
    if ($age >= 18 || $age < 59)
    {
        if ($work == 'employee')
        { 
            if ($place == 'rural') { $loan_credibility = 1; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've chaged the code as you suggested, the result is still same. but for this time it only display echo '$A' which is positive. previous, it only display the negative word as the result.

Comment: If age >= 18 || age < 59 is always true. Age 3 because 3 < 59 and age 105 >= 18. What you want to do is check >= 18 *&&* age < 59.

Comment: This is a bit misleading... If nothing should be done unless `$marital_stat` equals 'married' or 'single', then `else` is not actually required. My guess is that `$marital_stat` will be 'married' or 'single' whenever valid data is submitted, in which case maybe an `else` that handles an error could be helpful.

Comment: what does echo " ($marital_stat) "; produce? Have you tried $_POST ['marital_stat']?

Comment: @mike i already put the $marital_stat = ($_POST['marital_stat']); the result should be if if she married and jobless, it will display negative. but now, it display the positive.

Comment: @grossvogel: if the only values that matter are `married` and `single` the one if-block could cover `married` and another could cover `single`; this is completely inline with my proposed #1

Comment: All: part of what is throwing off results and troubleshooting is that, as @Mohamed Belal pointed out in his answer, there is incorrect use of `=` vs `==` when setting `$loan_credibility`... it should be `=`

Comment: @user1801810 i've already tried as suggested by Mohamed Belal, but it doesnt show any improvement.

Comment: @user1801810: you're technically correct that your `if` example achieves the same thing (at the cost of an unnecessary condition evaluation in the 'married' case), but the important point is that OP's use of `else if` is not the problem.

Comment: @grossvogel: `marital_stat` is already being evaluated twice in OP's code (first in `if` and second in `else if`) - the problem is we need more details as to what `$loan_credibility` would be if none of the conditions are true; otherwise `$loan_credibility` could be defaulted to 1 or 5 and changed if fewer conditions are met.